# Inverse momentum transfer in dark matter interaction

Tags: momentum, dark-matter

I'm reading papers about direct detection of dark matter and couldn't understand the term 'inverse momentum transfer'. Could someone please explain What the 'inverse' momentum transfer in the dark matter interaction with a standard model particle is, and why it matters?

Comment: Reference/ context please

Answer (score 0):

A scatter will involve some transfer of momentum.  When one of the objects involved in the scatter is extended in space (as a nucleus or an atom is, as opposed to an electron), then it makes sense to ask if there is a length scale relevant to the scatter, and compare that to the size of the scattering object. de Broglie tells us how to relate a momentum to a length:  L = h / p.  In this sense, the de Broglie wavelength is the inverse of the momentum.  If the inverse momentum transfer is the size of a proton, then you know that the interaction really only involves a single nucleon within the nucleus.  However, if the inverse momentum transfer is larger than a nucleus, you know that the entire nucleus must be participating in the scatter, not just a single nucleon (this is usually the case in dark matter direct detection).  At intermediate momentum transfer, where its inverse is comparable in size to a nucleus, interesting interference effects can appear, where some nucleons interfere with others in the scattering matrix.  If you look at the expected recoil energy spectrum of a WIMP scattering off a nucleus, you will notice that it has several energies where it drops to zero; this is a result of such interference.